# After installing wine laptop crashed

Tags: wine, crash

After installing Wine in my Linux laptop the laptop is not starting and crashed. I have not backed up my data. Please tell me what to do.

[image]

Comment: Does it stay like that beyond this point? Does it show any new message afterwards?

Comment: No, after this no messages are coming. Finally all data vanished and my laptop corrupt as told by local technician. Again I have reinstalled the linux

Comment: Before reinstalling, you could take a backup of the data by booting with a live USB (which you can also use to reinstall Ubuntu)